# Rails Production Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, production-environment

I'm new to rails have been searching for deployment guides on the web - it's quite fragmented. I see some which recommend deploying as a sudo enabled user. I was thinking you would create a user with no sudo powers to run the app for security reasons. It would need it's own home directory for RVM and bundler but having sudo powers seems redundant and a security risk. I'm doing this all manually as it's a tricky beta level application and deploying it is not yet straightforward, so capistrano would only be a layer of obfuscation at this point.

I'm using thin as the server with Nginx as the proxy and redis and Postgres as the database. Clockwork and sidekiq as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano seems like a lot of work even for a small project but it's worth getting setup anyway if you have hopes of the application growing (and thus the complexity of deployment increasing).

I personally like the idea of separating the distribution specific Ruby available (and gems) to an RVM deployment specific to the application.  Furthermore, requiring bundler to manage gem dependencies and ensuring compliance is invaluable.  I wouldn't suggest enabling sudo for that user; it'll expose the whole stack from HTTP requests to root level OS control.  Applications shouldn't require administrative access, deployment scripts might.

Comment: I've seen tutorials instructing you to install an app so that a sudo enabled user is running it. :P Would you put the application in /home/<username>/<app-repo> ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it really matters all that much but depends more on how the mount points are arranged or where you could put content.  Most probably find a home for their app in either the home dir of the user or somewhere in /var/www.  I'm personally inclined to use /var/www if the host might be used for multiple small apps.

Comment: Okay, would you do a chmod -R appuser:www-data /var/www/app? Nginx would need some access of course even though it's proxying to thin.

Comment: @EdwardWilliams Yes.  I would give RoR rwx permissions and Nginx r-x permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to Rails I'd recommend something simple for your first deployment.  [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) allows you to deploy apps by simply doing a git push to their repository.  They handle all the steps necessary to make your app available on the Internet.  Best of all it's free as long as you don't need heavy resources.

[EngineYard](http://www.engineyard.com) is another hosting solution that's easy to deploy to and step up from Heroku in terms of flexibility (and cost).

Once you're comfortable with deploying production apps then you can look to using your own servers and using capistrano for the ultimate in customization.

I have production websites running in both environments and I've yet to need to go to the trouble of migrating to my own hosted server.